# Is there lead paint on my 80-105 year old piano?

Tags: toxicity

I have an old piano made in Czechoslovakia it's somewhere between 80-105 years old. The brand/maker/company's name is Weinbach. It no longer works because all the notes are ripped out i want to turn it into a desk, but i have to sand down the paint to repaint it but i don't know if it's safe. Thanks for the help!

Comment: We can only guess, possibly incorrectly. Why not test it?

Comment: *"but i have to sand down the paint to repaint it"* Why do you have to do that?

Comment: Rather amazingly, we have a previous Q on almost exactly the same topic. [Could there be lead in the finish of a mid-century piano?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/could-there-be-lead-in-the-finish-of-a-mid-century-piano)

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, this seems like the soundest course of action. But regrettably there's a catch: consumer-level testing kits are unreliable, one might even say notoriously unreliable; based on this the alternative is usually considered too expensive to bear. So the safest course of action if one wants to err on the side of caution is to assume there is lead (and at toxic levels) and proceed accordingly.

Comment: In the Us ,pianos are usually varnished , not painted ( no pigments),

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for us to know.  But it is old enough that it is certainly a possibility.  So your options are to either have it tested, or assume that is has leaded paint and take the proper precautions when dealing with leaded paint removal.

One option would be to use paint remover to limit how much paint is air born by not sanding it (as much)